# How did Frodo get to know the story of Sméagol?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers, gollum

In The Two Towers film, Frodo is talking to Gollum in the Dead Marshes when he says:

> You were not so very different from a Hobbit once, were you?

before using Gollum's original name, and makes some other remarks that indicate that he knows at least part of the story of Sméagol. Where did he get this knowledge and why does he suddenly recognize him?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't remember for sure in the movies, but in the book, Gandalf tells Frodo a great deal of the tale of Smeagol while Frodo is still in the Shire. (He does this in the context of telling him about the Ring and its history, and why Frodo will have to leave for Rivendell or somewhere else.) Additionally, Gandalf tells the full story to the Council of Elrond at Rivendell, at which Frodo was present. So in the context of the book, Frodo always knew that Gollum was once a hobbit (not just "like a hobbit" but an actual hobbit), and always knew that Gollum had murdered his friend for the Ring and then fled to the caves of the Misty Mountains.

---

In the movies, Gandalf and Frodo have a discussion about Gollum as they're going through Moria.  Presumably we only see a portion of this conversation and this is when Frodo learns the rest of Gollum/Smeagol's background.

Comment: Ohh, you're one of *those people.*

Comment: @Keen: Why not make this another answer!? It gives you rep and is good for the beta answer ratio (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy) … I recommend you write your own …

Comment: @FelixDombek Eh, I figured it was better for everyone if we had one complete answer instead of 2 half answers.  Also, to say I don't really need more rep is an understatement.

Comment: I believe the discussion in the movie was only in the extended edition and was edited out of the theatrical release.

Comment: I think the chapter in The Fellowship of the Ring is called "The Shadow of the Past" (chapter 2).

Answer (score -1):

In the movies, when Frodo first spies Gollum stalking them in the Misty Mountains (Moria) he informs Gandalf who tells him a little of Gollum's history.